# Loopback: saving model relations to database

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, relation, loopbackjs

I have been reading model relations in Loopback, but I am not sure how you would save relations when persisting data models. Let me use the following example.

Two models: **Category**, and **Article**

```
A Category has many Articles, which uses a foreign key categoryId
```

Suppose there is a web page that has a drop-down category list and the value for each category in the list is their auto-incremented `Id` in database. Below the drop-down list, there's an input field and a text box for you to input article title and text body. Now my question is :

When you hit the save button, the `Article model` along with the selected `category Id` to the POST API for articles. I was wondering how you would save the one-to-many relation. Do you retrieve the category object for the category Id and save it with the aricle object or you would just save the article object with the category Id in the **Article** database table?

I have a background in Hibernate, but not sure how to use the relation properly in loopback. Replies are appreciated very much, and an example would be great.

**Edit**: well this is not a direct answer to my question, but I found this github repo very helpful in achieving what I was looking for, and it offers good examples for integrating angularJS and loopback as the backend.
It's here: https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to post the answer I got from **Líus Fontenelle Carneiro** at the google group for Loopback, just in case someone in future has the same question.

```
    Assuming you have Category hasMany Articles, Category endpoint will receive
by default a URL to handle the relation CRUD operations (e.g.
/categories/id/articles). When performing a POST to this URL, you're giving the
id that loopback will look for at the first place. If found, its id 
automatically fill related foreign key on Article nested model, together with
other fields you sent to fill Article properties.
```